# Is 'this follows from~' grammatically right?

Tags: word-usage

I have never heard of this expression, 'this follows from~.' Is it grammatically correct? I can't say I rely on the article in Wikipedia.

> SMS language is similar to that used by those sending telegraphs that
>   charged by the word. It seeks to use the fewest number of letters to
>   produce ultra-concise words and sentiments[2] in dealing with space,
>   time and cost constraints of text messaging. This **follows from** how
>   early SMS permitted only 160 characters and some carriers charge
>   messages by the number of characters sent.[3]
>
> It also shares some of these characteristics with Internet slang and
>   Telex speak **following from** how its evolution is rather symbiotic
>   to the evolution of use of shorthand in Internet chat rooms.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SMS_language

Answer (score 6):

Yes, ["this follows from"](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=this%20follows%20from&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cthis%20follows%20from%3B%2Cc0) is both grammatically correct and idiomatic, although the linked ngram suggests that its use peaked in the 1960s. "This follows from" usually means **"This came about because of"**  the preceding conditions in the sentence or paragraph before it.

The second example is a poorly constructed sentence, and "following from how" sounds contrived and awkward to my ear. It might better have been stated as follows:

> SMS language also shares some of these characteristics with Internet slang and "Telex-speak," as it evolved alongside the use of shorthand in Internet chat rooms.

Comment: Thank you, Mr. Hubbard. One more question, please. What does 'follow from' mean? Does it mean 'to be a logical consequence'?

Comment: I've edited my answer to address your follow-up question. Once one is in the habit of using a phrase like "this follows from," a writer may tend to over-use it, as is the case in your example from Wikipedia.

Comment: I don't much like the cited use of ***how*** in a context where it clearly carries the sense of *the **fact** that [something was done]* rather than the ***way*** it was done. It sounds "slangy" to me, at odds with the "semi-formal" construction *X follows from Y*.

Comment: In math discussions, "A follows from B" is a standard locution meaning that B can be  deduced logically from A. Ask any mathematician. If I were writing history, which once upon a time I planned to do, I  probably would be reluctant to use the construction because it implies to me the kind of logical rigor that history almost never can claim.